# Updating a dense vector by a sparse vector in Julia is slow

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I am using Julia version 0.4.5 and I am experiencing the following issue:
As far as I know, taking inner product between a sparse vector and a dense vector should be as fast as updating the dense vector by a sparse vector. The latter one is much slower.

```
A = sprand(100000,100000,0.01)
w = rand(100000)

@time for i=1:100000
  w += A[:,i]
end
26.304380 seconds (1.30 M allocations: 150.556 GB, 8.16% gc time)

@time for i=1:100000
  A[:,i]'*w
end
0.815443 seconds (921.91 k allocations: 1.540 GB, 5.58% gc time)
```

I created a simple sparse matrix type of my own, and the addition code was ~ the same as the inner product.

Am I doing something wrong? I feel like there should be a special function doing the operation w += A[:,i], but I couldn't find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your 2 methods are not equivalent. The first one could be replaced by `w += sum(A, 2)` without the for loop (first reduce `A` over columns, then update `w`). Is that what you want?

Comment: If so, the timings are `0.348840 seconds (75 allocations: 1.530 MB)`.

Comment: @imaluengo I want to write an iterative method, where I will update w by some number times the column of the matrix. I am just simulating that by doing a lot of additions, showcasing that it is incredibly slow. As I mentioned, doing `w += c*A[:,i]` should take ~ the same time as `A[:,i]'*w`. I did my own sparse implementation and I got ~1 second for both. I am just wondering whether it can be done with the SparseMatrixCSC class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on GitHub and we came to the following conclusion. The type SparseVector was added as of Julia 0.4 and with it the BLAS function LinAlg.axpy!, which updates in-place a (possibly dense) vector `x` by a sparse vector `y` multiplied by a scalar `a`, i.e. performs `x += a*y` efficiently. However, in Julia 0.4 it is not implemented properly. It works only in Julia 0.5

```
@time for i=1:100000
  LinAlg.axpy!(1,A[:,i],w)
end
1.041587 seconds (799.49 k allocations: 1.530 GB, 8.01% gc time)
```

However, this code is still sub-optimal, as it creates the SparseVector A[:,i]. One can get an even faster version with the following function:

```
function upd!(w,A,i,c)
  rowval = A.rowval
  nzval = A.nzval
  @inbounds for j = nzrange(A,i)
    w[rowval[j]] += c* nzval[j]
  end
  return w
end

@time for i=1:100000
  upd!(w,A,i,1)
end
0.500323 seconds (99.49 k allocations: 1.518 MB)
```

This is exactly what I needed to achieve, after some research we managed to get there, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compute `w += c * A[:, i]`, there is an easy way to vectorize it:

```
>>> A = sprand(100000, 100000, 0.01)
>>> c = rand(100000)

>>> r1 = zeros(100000)
>>> @time for i = 1:100000
>>>    r1 += A[:, i] * c[i]
>>> end
29.997412 seconds (1.90 M allocations: 152.077 GB, 12.73% gc time)

>>> @time r2 = sum(A .* c', 2);
1.191850 seconds (50 allocations: 1.493 GB, 0.14% gc time)

>>> all(r1 == r2)
true
```

First, create a vector `c` of the constants to multiply with. Then multiplay de columns of `A` element-wise by the values of `c` (`A .* c'`, it does broadcasting inside). Last, reduce over the columns of `A` (the part `sum(.., 2)`).

Comment: I understand all of this, but my point is, that this has to be part of my iterative algorithm, i.e. at each iteration `t`, i want to update `w += c(w)*A[:,i]` for a random index `i`, where `c(w)` is a function of the current `w`. This means, that I cannot vectorize it, because it is a serial algorithm. Therefore my question really is, why is the addition slower than multiplication, because it definitely should not be in a good sparse implementation.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that there are still ways of vectorizing what you want to do. But anyway, the reason might be that multiplication is `precompiled` while your for loop is being interpreted. Try putting your for loop into a function and *precompiling* it, you might get better speeds.

Comment: Unfortunately, putting it inside a function did not help. My goal is something similar to the following: `for t=1:T ; i = rand(length(w)); w+= (X[:,i]'*w)*X[:,i] ; end`. It is special case of stochastic gradient descent - a serial optimization algorithm. Each iteration should take O(nnz(X[:,i])) flops. Taking the inner product works according to the theory, adding it up to w takes a lot more (as shown in the timing in the original post). I am pretty sure that I am using a wrong command for updating w, or there is an issue with SparseMatrixCSC.